# Get nid in views custom PHP argument

Tags: views

i want to limit node reference (autocomplete widget) based on one of CCK field on current node. So, i made view to limit results and in argument->Provide default argument->PHP Code.
And write code like this:

```
$mynode = node_load(arg(1));
return $mynode->field_foo[0]['nid'];
```

But problem is in that arg(1) is not returning NID of current page but string 'autocomplete' (i guess it is name of function).
(Didn't had luck with [menu_get_object()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--menu.inc/function/menu_get_object/6) either)

So how can i get NID of current node other than using ARG() in views custom PHP argument?

Can i reference directly on CCK field (yes, as I sad it is on samo page as autocomplete text-field)?

Thanks for help.

UPDATE: 
This is specific to autocomplete widget.

It works well with other widget types (select list, checkbox...)

Comment: Can you add the output of a var_dump($_GET['q']); to your question please?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to have the current NID of the viewed page in your view, you should use the following:

In your view:
At the Arguments section you select "Node:nid", in the configuration of this argument at "Action to take if argument is not present:" you can choose "Provide default argument" after that you choose "Node ID from URL".

And there you have your NID in your view.

Comment: Tnx for reply, but i need to have NID in my function so I can access CCK field on page.

Answer (score 1):

Lets say if you have these fields in a node creation form. 
Like

1. Select Field
2. Auto-complete

And the auto-complete should show results based on the first field.
Now you ll be using the auto-complete even before this node is created right? means the nid of the node will not be created yet.

Or is it like, the nid that you want to pass is that of the result in the 1st field ?

Comment: Auto complete should be based on selection made on select field both on node create and node edit.